# resolve the issue of possible the underlying files have been updated in data bricks

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

```
val mnt_point_write="/mnt/pnt" 
ord_JsonDF.write.mode("overwrite").format("json").option("header",true).json(mnt_point_write+"/Processed_file")



Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: 
    Task 0 in stage 114.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: 
    Lost task 0.3 in stage 114.0 (TID 13876, 10.139.64.40, executor 27): 
    com.databricks.sql.io.FileReadException: Error while reading file dbfs:/mnt-02/AF_tab/Processed/YYYY=2019/MM=07/DD=21/part-00000-tid-677839983764655717-ahfuhaufhehfhurfawefkjfaffadfe-2685-1.c000.csv. 
    It is possible the underlying files have been updated. 
    You can explicitly invalidate the cache in Spark by running 'REFRESH TABLE tableName' command in SQL or by recreating the Dataset/DataFrame involved.
```

Coming across the above issue. Can anyone help in resolving the issue please.

Comment: Need more input. Which API are you using to consume the underlying file. A code snippet would be helpful.

Comment: this occur when you load dataFrame into Memory and make changes in file. Please reload /read data again.

Comment: @Nikk yes realoading helps resolve the issue, but this happens on a regular basis. any work around for the above challenge

Comment: @KumarRohit
val mnt_point_write="/mnt/pnt" 
 
//writing nested json to BDL 
Ors_JsonDF.write.mode("overwrite").format("json").option("header",true).json(mnt_point_write+"/Processed file")

Comment: Request you to edit question and provide code snippet for better understanding of your problem statement.

Comment: @KumarRohit updated the code snippent

Comment: How about you make your `DF` `lazy`? While creating the DataFrame, if you make it lazy, it will be created (read) only when an action is performed on top of that `DataFrame`. That way even if the data is updated while your code runs, Spark should pick up the files only once.

Comment: @KumarRohit could you please share me like how this could be implemented

Comment: Just add the keyword `lazy` while creating a dataframe. For example you can refer to the code from my usecase - `lazy val adsDf = spark.read.format("csv"). ... `

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206276/discussion-between-kumar-rohit-and-pradyot-mohanty).

Comment: is this resolved ?